# Dealing with good questions in bad English

Tags: discussion, flagging, questions

I've seen a few questions in the review queue that seem as though they conform to the SE standards but that have so many grammatical issues it's exceptionally difficult to be sure. How do you suggest that these questions be handled? I certainly don't want to discourage anyone from participating or seeking help when they need it.

Comment: Anecdotal comment: Once I saw a question flagged for being in French. My response was to Google Translate that sucker, fix the grammar, and reject the flag. The point being it could always be worse. If it's salvageable, I'd try to save it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since English is the only allowed language I think our only option is to edit the question the best way we can. The user posting bad English will hopefully learn along the way, and we get a stronger community if we help each other out.

English is really tough to learn if you native language is traditional Chinese. Not only do you need to learn letter structure in stead of word symbols, but you do that with limited access to English resources.

So my suggestion is: **edit** if you can, and flag if you can't and we'll take a look at it.